# Separating steady state component from a line graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any module/method in python to filter out the transient part in a graph?
I have a graph that includes a transient component and a steady state component. I am trying to extract the steady state value from graph generated using matplotlib.
The code used and the resulting graph are as follows:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

per_data=genfromtxt('output-3.csv',delimiter=',',names=['x', 'y'])
print(type(per_data))
plt.xlabel ('x stuff')
plt.ylabel ('y stuff')
plt.title('my test result')
plt.plot(per_data['y'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is this something that can't be solved by just removing your initial data from the plot? I mean, just getting everything from `x stuff = 1000` onwards

Comment: I have 100 such graphs being generated so I was thinking of automating the process of separating the steady state in a way as much amount of information as possible is retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can effectively define steady state response as parts of a graph where the absolute value of the derivative of that point is nearly 0, that is to say the rate of change is nearly 0.  Likewise we can say the opposite, if the absolute value of the derivative is larger than nearly 0, its transient.

This should be fairly easy to filter out, but when you say " separating the steady state" you could mean really a million things.   Do you want to only keep the steady state?  Do you only want to keep contiguous steady state?  What do you do with the parts in between the steady state?   You've neglected to specify what you want here so I'm just going to show you how you would separate both parts and you can decide what you want to do with them afterwards.

First decide what you want as a derivative bound.  You can experiment with this, I'm just going to pick 0.1. We then need to figure out how to calculate the derivative.   Our data is apparently (from what you show) not continuous.  A simple numerical method via finding slope to approximate the derivative between adjacent points should be appropriate for your problem then.

You'll apply this derivative to each pair on your graph and then you can filter the list based on those derivative values.

Here's an example:

```
#spacing is the distance between each point on the x axis
def find_derivative(y1, y2, spacing)
    return (y2 - y1)/ spacing

# note index should obviously be < len and not negative, but garbage 
# in garbage out, so no need for an assertion on that point
def consecutive_derivative(datapoints, index, spacing)
    assert len(datapoints) >= 2, "Error, why would we need the derivative of one point?"
    if index < (len(datapoints)):
        y1 = list[index]
        y2 = list[index+1]
    else:
        y1 = list[index-1]
        y2 = list[index]

    return find_derivative(y1, y2, spacing)

def to_derivative_list(datapoints, spacing):
    return [consecutive_derivative(datapoints, i, spacing) for i in range(len(datapoints)] 


# ... some code for list creation ...

steady_state_cutoff = 0.1
derivatives = to_derivative_list(per_data, per_data_spacing)
steady_state_indicies = []
transient_state_indicies = []
for index, derivative in enumerate(derivatives):
    if abs(derivative) < steady_state_cutoff
        steady_state_indicies.append(index)
    else
        transient_state_indicies.append(index)
#now you even have each index which is a steady state and
#those that are transient, so you can form your own new graphs off of
#these
```